# Select Columns IF condition else return as columns

Tags: sql

Hi I have a condition for 1 column and it should go like this

```
 select    
 WHEN NM1.nm101 = 'IL' THEN ( CLP.Segment_GUID as CLPSegmentGuid,
                              NM1.NM102 as [INSURED_Entity_Type_Qualifier],
                              NM1.NM103 as [INSURED_Entity_Last_Name],
                              NM1.NM104 as [INSURED_Entity_First_Name],
                              NM1.NM105 as [INSURED_Entity_Middle_Name],
                              NM1.NM108 as [INSURED_Entity_Identification_Code_Type],
                              NM1.NM109 as [INSURED_Entity_Identification_Code])



 WHEN NM1.nm101 = '74' THEN ( CLP.Segment_GUID as CLPSegmentGuid,
                              NM1.NM102 as [Corrected_Entity_Type_Qualifier],
                              NM1.NM103 as [Corrected_Entity_Last_Name],
                              NM1.NM104 as [Corrected_Entity_First_Name],
                              NM1.NM105 as [Corrected_Entity_Middle_Name],
                              NM1.NM108 as [Corrected_Entity_Identification_Code_Type],
                              NM1.NM109 as [Corrected_Entity_Identification_Code])



ELSE NM1.nm101 = '82' THEN ( CLP.Segment_GUID as CLPSegmentGuid,
                              NM1.NM102 as [CROSSOVER_Entity_Type_Qualifier],
                              NM1.NM103 as [CROSSOVER_Entity_Last_Name],
                              NM1.NM104 as [CROSSOVER_Entity_First_Name],
                              NM1.NM105 as [CROSSOVER_Entity_Middle_Name],
                              NM1.NM108 as [CROSSOVER_Entity_Identification_Code_Type],
                              NM1.NM109 as [CROSSOVER_Entity_Identification_Code])



          From  X12_NM1 NM1 
          Inner Join X12_CLP CLP
          ON CLP.segment_guid = NM1.parent_segment_guid
```

so for that particular column NM101 while doing select statement i have to see the condition and return the columns , can any one help regarding this.

Comment: A single static query will always return a result set with the same shape - that is, it will always produce the same number of columns, and those column *names* and types will be fixed.

Comment: Sooo... what you want can only be done with either 1) *multiple* static queries (presumably in a procedure with `IF..THEN..ELSE`s), or 2) with dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option for you to consider

```
SELECT NM1.nm101
     , CLP.Segment_GUID as CLPSegmentGuid
     , CASE NM1.nm101
         WHEN 'IL' THEN 'INSURED'
         WHEN '74' THEN 'Corrected'
         WHEN '82' THEN 'Crossover'
       END As type       
     , NM1.NM102 As Entity_Type_Qualifier
     , NM1.NM103 As Entity_Last_Name
     , NM1.NM104 As Entity_First_Name
     , NM1.NM105 As Entity_Middle_Name
     , NM1.NM108 As Entity_Identification_Code_Type
     , NM1.NM109 As Entity_Identification_Code
FROM   X12_NM1 As NM1 
 INNER
  JOIN X12_CLP As CLP
    ON CLP.segment_guid = NM1.parent_segment_guid
WHERE  NM1.nm101 IN ('IL', '74', '82')
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change the output columns in the middle of a query.  One option is to return ALL columns and fill them based on your conditions:

```
select    
     CLP.Segment_GUID as CLPSegmentGuid,
     CASE WHEN NM1.nm101 = 'IL' THEN NM1.NM102 ELSE NULL as [INSURED_Entity_Type_Qualifier],
     CASE WHEN NM1.nm101 = 'IL' THEN NM1.NM103 ELSE NULL as [INSURED_Entity_Last_Name],
     CASE WHEN NM1.nm101 = 'IL' THEN NM1.NM104 ELSE NULL as [INSURED_Entity_First_Name],
     CASE WHEN NM1.nm101 = 'IL' THEN NM1.NM105 ELSE NULL as [INSURED_Entity_Middle_Name],
     CASE WHEN NM1.nm101 = 'IL' THEN NM1.NM108 ELSE NULL as [INSURED_Entity_Identification_Code_Type],
     CASE WHEN NM1.nm101 = 'IL' THEN NM1.NM109 ELSE NULL as [INSURED_Entity_Identification_Code],

     CASE WHEN NM1.nm101 = '74' THEN NM1.NM102 ELSE NULL as [Corrected_Entity_Type_Qualifier],
     CASE WHEN NM1.nm101 = '74' THEN NM1.NM103 ELSE NULL as [Corrected_Entity_Last_Name],
     CASE WHEN NM1.nm101 = '74' THEN NM1.NM104 ELSE NULL as [Corrected_Entity_First_Name],
     CASE WHEN NM1.nm101 = '74' THEN NM1.NM105 ELSE NULL as [Corrected_Entity_Middle_Name],
     CASE WHEN NM1.nm101 = '74' THEN NM1.NM108 ELSE NULL as [Corrected_Entity_Identification_Code_Type],
     CASE WHEN NM1.nm101 = '74' THEN NM1.NM109 ELSE NULL as [Corrected_Entity_Identification_Code],

     CASE WHEN NM1.nm101 = '82' THEN NM1.NM102 ELSE NULL as [CROSSOVER_Entity_Type_Qualifier],
     CASE WHEN NM1.nm101 = '82' THEN NM1.NM103 ELSE NULL as [CROSSOVER_Entity_Last_Name],
     CASE WHEN NM1.nm101 = '82' THEN NM1.NM104 ELSE NULL as [CROSSOVER_Entity_First_Name],
     CASE WHEN NM1.nm101 = '82' THEN NM1.NM105 ELSE NULL as [CROSSOVER_Entity_Middle_Name],
     CASE WHEN NM1.nm101 = '82' THEN NM1.NM108 ELSE NULL as [CROSSOVER_Entity_Identification_Code_Type],
     CASE WHEN NM1.nm101 = '82' THEN NM1.NM109 ELSE NULL as [CROSSOVER_Entity_Identification_Code]

From  X12_NM1 NM1 
Inner Join X12_CLP CLP
ON CLP.segment_guid = NM1.parent_segment_guid
```

It's not pretty but if you need all of those results in one result set it may be the best option.  My preference would be to use more generic column names and let the consumer decide what to call it based on the appropriate condition:

```
select    
     CLP.Segment_GUID as CLPSegmentGuid,
     CASE 
         WHEN NM1.nm101 = 'IL' THEN 'INSURED'
         WHEN NM1.nm101 = '74' THEN 'Corrected'
         WHEN NM1.nm101 = '82' THEN 'CROSSOVER'
         ELSE 'Unknown'
     END as Category,
     NM1.NM102 as [Entity_Type_Qualifier],
     NM1.NM103 as [Entity_Last_Name],
     NM1.NM104 as [Entity_First_Name],
     NM1.NM105 as [Entity_Middle_Name],
     NM1.NM108 as [Entity_Identification_Code_Type],
     NM1.NM109 as [Entity_Identification_Code]
From  X12_NM1 NM1 
Inner Join X12_CLP CLP
ON CLP.segment_guid = NM1.parent_segment_guid
```

Comment: iam getting this error Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near 'NM1'.

Comment: Edited - Left in a few parens that should have been taken out and missed adding a few commas.